# Use flow logic to skip a step in Transloadit assembly?

Tags: transloadit

Is it possible to use the flow logic or file filtering in Transloadit to convert a PNG to a JPG if the uploaded file is not already a JPG, but skip the step and continue with the other processing steps otherwise?

From what I can see from the docs, you can only halt an assembly if a condition is or isnt met..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the /file/filter robot to pass `:original` files only to an /image/resize step if it matches your conditions.

You should disable `error_on_decline` to make this filtering seamless.

Here's more information on the [/file/filter robot](https://transloadit.com/docs/conversion-robots/#file-filtering-with-the-filefilter-bot) and here are all the [variables you can use to filter by](https://transloadit.com/docs/#assembly-variables).

Looks like you could use either `${file.ext}` or maybe `${file.mime}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Getting the hang of this now :)